# How to make navigation drawer shrink (mini version) once hamburger is clicked?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I create Vue2 app using Vuex. I added navbar and navigation drawer. There is a hamburger on the left side of the navbar which toggles navigation drawer. I can click on drawer's element and expand the drawer. The issue is that when I toggle a drawer then it disappears completely, the it appears again when hamburger is clicked again. What I want to achieve is to toggle a drawer (when expanded) in a way it's shrinked to minified version.I'll show what I got now:

1. initial view:

[image]

2. I click on drawer's element (e.g. plane) to expand it:

[image]

3. I click the hamburger to shrink the drawer (to mini version with icons only):

[image]

And as you can see drawer is not visible, it disappears. And here is the example app where you see what I bear in mind. Look how navigation drawer and hamburger works: https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-paper-dashboard-pro/?_ga=2.12802551.151259280.1666643495-739984285.1666643495#/admin/overview

Here is my code:

**Navbar.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-app-bar app>
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click="setDrawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
  </v-app-bar>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations } from 'vuex'

export default {

methods: {
    ...mapMutations('custom', ['setDrawer'])
  }
}
</script>
```

**NavDrawer.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer
    app
    :mini-variant.sync="mini"
    v-model="toggleDrawer"   
    >
    
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>

      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <v-list
      nav>
      <v-list-item-group
        v-model="selectedItem"
        color="primary"
        >
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon> {{ item.icon }} </v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title> {{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    data () {
      return {
        selectedItem: 0,
        mini: true,
        items: [
          { text: "1", icon: "mdi-airplane" },
          { text: "2", icon: "mdi-ferry" },
          { text: "3", icon: "mdi-truck" }
        ]
  }
},

computed: {
    ...mapState('custom', ['toggleDrawer']),
}
}
</script>
```

**Vuex - custom.js:**

```
const state = {
    toggleDrawer: true,
};

const mutations = {
    setDrawer: (state) => state.toggleDrawer = !state.toggleDrawer
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    mutations
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `:mini-variant.sync="mini"` with `:mini-variant.sync="toggleDrawer"` and remove the v-model. This binds your Vuex store's variable with Vuetify's default expand/collapse behaviour. Moreover, you can remove "mini" from your data attributes.

Comment: Yes, I followed this docs. As you could notice, there is a small icon which shrinks the drawer, I mean ` <v-btn icon @click.stop="mini = !mini"><v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon></v-btn>` where `mini=true` in `data()`. The issue is that I want to use hamburger in navbar instead to shrink the drawer. And don't know how to do it. Removing first v-list doesn't change anything

Comment: Ok, then replace :mini-variant.sync="mini" with :mini-variant.sync="toggleDrawer" and remove the v-model. That should work

Comment: Did this solve your issue?

Comment: yes, it almost works fine except for the fact that when I click an element on a drawer (e.g. ship) then drawer does not expand.